# how to write a where clause in sqlite query to gain the exact value?

Tags: android, sqlite

hi i have a poem database and i want to search in the poems this is what my code look like now
public ArrayList searchthequeryforme(String inputText) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_TEXT, KEY_TITLE };
    Cursor c = mydatabase.query(true,TABLE_POEM, columns, KEY_TEXT+" like '%"+inputText+"%'", null, null,
            null, null, null);
    ArrayList<poem> myarray = new ArrayList<poem>();

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        poem = new poem(c.getInt(0), c.getString(1), c.getString(2));
        myarray.add(poem);

    }
    return myarray;

}
```

but in this case if i search for "poem" for example it retrieves the records in which i have "poet" and it comes with a text that actually doesnt have "poem" i want to get the exact records what should my query look like?

Answer (score 2):

That's what the `LIKE` operator does. To get an exact match, change

```
KEY_TEXT+" like '%"+inputText+"%'"
```

to

```
KEY_TEXT+"='"+inputText+"'";
```

Comment: no it doesnt work because i have a textview full of text and i want to search for a word in that not the whole text i mean my key_text is filled with a poem which has 200 characters and i want to search for a single word on that.

Comment: Hmm, well then the LIKE operator is what you need. Make sure the `inputText` is correct. `LIKE '%poem%'` will return only ones that have "poem" in it. Otherwise I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: YOu saved my life :P

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in using framework instead of coding the database access code, then, please look at Active Android (http://www.activeandroid.com/). It has some very nice query access API as you can from examples here: https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/wiki/Querying-the-database